# How bind observable of observable in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have function like

```
function Configuration(data) {
var self = this;
self.configKey = data.pKey;
self.configName = data.configName;
self.configNumber = data.modelnumber;
self.configMTP = ko.observable(data.mTP);
self.configMDP = ko.observable(data.mDP);
}
```

And my view model like

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.Configurations = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selConfig = ko.observable();
}
```

And binding is like below

```
  <select data-bind="options:categories,optionsCaption:'All',value:selCatgy ">
  </select>
```

The Configurations array in the viewmodel has the list of configuration objects. When user selects particular configuration the selected 'selConfig' property is getting updated with selected configuration object.. 
Now if i want to bind the other properties(like configMTP,configMDP) in the screen from 'selConfig', is it possible to do?

I did something like below. Is there any other way we can achieve the same?

```
 <!-- ko foreach:selConfig-->
    <pre data-bind="text: configMTP"></pre>
    <input data-bind="value: configMDP" />
    <input data-bind="value: configName" />
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Thanks,

Praveen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind to **one** objects properties you need to use the [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) instead of the `foreach`:

```
<!-- ko with: selConfig -->
    <pre data-bind="text: configMTP"></pre>
    <input data-bind="value: configMDP" />
    <input data-bind="value: configName" />
 <!-- /ko -->
```